# Qt tcp/ip server works with telnet, but not python or netcat

Tags: qt, networking, tcp

I have a Qt tcp/ip server listening on a port. I can talk to it with telnet, but when I try with netcat the input commands are truncated. When I try to send it a command through python, it doesn't see anything. Has anyone else run into an issue like this with a Qt tcp server? Code follows.

Server

```
QTcpServer remoteControlServer;

remoteControlClient = remoteControlServer.nextPendingConnection();

connect(remoteControlClient, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(remoteCommandRead()));
```

The command interpreter -> This is where I suspect the problem is. Is canReadLine() not doing what I want? I am just sending strings, so the line-oriented protocol is what I think I should be using.

```
 void MainWindow::remoteCommandRead()
 {
    QByteArray lineBuffer; 
    QByteArray consoleString;
    QByteArray command;
    QList<QByteArray> commandList;

    while(remoteControlClient->canReadLine())
        {
            lineBuffer = remoteControlClient->readLine();
            lineBuffer.chop(2);
            lineBuffer.simplified();

            commandList = lineBuffer.split(' ');
```

The python client

```
import socket
remote_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('address', port)
remote_sock.connect(server_address)
remote_sock.sendall('commandString')
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Update: using PuTTy I discovered that there is some junk hanging around somewhere which I need to flush, but I don't know how much there is, where it is coming from or how to filter it out. 
When I enter a command using PuTTy the first time, the Qtserver side replies 
Unknown: ���� ����'������connect. 
The next time it gets 
Unknown: ���� ����'��'connect'
Then 
Unknown: ��$connect
And eventually it works and accepts the command 
Command: connect

Any ideas about what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
trimmedLineBuffer = lineBuffer.trimmed();
commandList = trimmedLineBuffer.split(' ');
```

instead of

```py
lineBuffer.chop(2);
lineBuffer.simplified();
```

From python append "/r/n" to the end of the string you are sending and everything will work fine!